# Set edit widget to read-only via PyQGIS for QGIS 2.8

Tags: qgis

I am trying to set an editor widget to read-only using PyQGIS. This would be the equivalent of setting the widget to Text edit and unchecking editable via the GUI.

I am using QGIS 2.8.3 and am have set the widget in this way:

```
myLayer.setEditorWidgetV2(fieldNameIDX, 'TextEdit')
```

I notice in the API for QGIS 2.15 that there is a new QgsEditFormConfig class with a readOnly method, but I believe I can't use it because of my QGIS version and I cannot immediately update.